# Apache2 Redirecting WWW to Naked Domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2

My apache2 virtual host file for example.com is as below. I'm using this with wordpress site.

I set up the site without bothering to redirect the naked domain to www. When I try and add any code to rewrite the URL it redirects back to the naked domain (301 redirect) and I'm in a redirect loop.

I can't figure out why my stack is redirecting www to naked domain. Any help appreciated. Standard LAMP stack with wordpress.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also my DNS is set up with an A NAME for www pointing to the server IP address.

Comment: That code/config wouldn't do that. Perhaps WP config (which I try to stay away from), or `.htaccess` rules?

Comment: Thanks. I made sure the .htaccess files didn't have any rules. I wonder what could be going on with wordpress config

Comment: Something like explained here? http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL